# React Native Gifted Chat: Hide other user's avatar

Tags: react-native-gifted-chat

Is there a way to hide the other user's avatar too for react native gifted chat? I know you can hide the current user's avatar but I can't find it for the other user.

Answer (score 3):

You can rewrite the Avatar component which will return null, in renderAvatar property.

For example:

```
<CustomGiftedChat
      messages={messages}
      renderAvatar={() => null}
      onSend={this.onSend}
      user={{
        _id: 1,
      }}
    />
```